# Displaying images on angular app from node server

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I have a nodejs app running on localhost:3000, I uploaded images using multer, so they are in ./uploads/ folder.
In the Angular app running on locahost:4200 I want to retrieve those images.

in my for loop: ( projectImages is the array of images for every Project Object)

```
<div *ngFor="let i of project.projectImages">
   <img [src]=i.path alt="" > 
</div>
```

the problem is that the path is being displayed as : localhost:4200/uploads/image.png instead of localhost:3000/uploads/image.png

**UPDATE:**
With that fixed by adding a variable to the component, I'm now getting :

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value
```

any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE2**:
this is my component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectService } from '../services/project.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-details',
  templateUrl: './project-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-details.component.css']
})
export class ProjectDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  project:any;
  apiUrl :string = "localhost:3000";
  project_id:string;

  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private projectService:ProjectService,
    private _location: Location,
    private sanitization: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    this.activatedRoute.params
    .subscribe( params => {
      console.log(params.project_id)
      this.project_id = params.project_id;
      this.getProjectByID(params.project_id);
    })
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

getProjectByID(project_id:string){
  this.projectService.getProjectById(project_id).subscribe((data:any) => {
    this.project = data.project;
    this.project.projectImages.map(image => {
      image.path = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`${this.apiUrl}/${image.path}`.replace(/\\/g,"/"));
      console.log(image);
      return image;
});
    console.log(this.project.projectImages); 
  } , err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
}
```

NOTE: `project.projectImages` is an array containing the images, this is what it looks like: https://ibb.co/jEgszo

Comment: You are using a relative path. If you want to use 3000 instead of 4200, give full path for [src].

`[src]='localhost:3000\'+i.path` or you may store address `localhost:3000` in a variable in ts file and use that variable in html

Comment: I already tried that and it says " Quotes are not supported for evaluation!"

Comment: No it's not a typo, i.path is from the for loop and needs to be concatenated with "localhost:3000\" .. I spent way too much time on this

Comment: so I declared a variable and set localhost:3000 to it and now I'm getting WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value

Comment: use `[src]='server+i.path'`. Set `server = "localhost:3000/"` in .ts

Comment: You can bypass the security. See this https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis

Answer (score 0):

use full path and sanitize the url before use

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';

export class YourClass{
  project;
  apiUrl;

  constructor(private sanitization: DomSanitizer) {
      this.apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
      project.projectImages.map(image => {
        image.path = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`${this.apiUrl}/${image.path}`);
        return image;
  });
  }
}
```

then in your html you can do this

```
<div *ngFor="let i of project.projectImages">
   <img [src]=i.path alt="" > 
</div>
```

your complete code will look something like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectService } from '../services/project.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-project-details',
    templateUrl: './project-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./project-details.component.css']
})
export class ProjectDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    project: any;
    apiUrl: string;
    project_id: string;
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private _location: Location,
    private sanitization: DomSanitizer
) {
    this.apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;

    this.activatedRoute.params
        .subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params.project_id)
            this.project_id = params.project_id;
            this.getProjectByID(params.project_id);
        })
}

ngOnInit() {
}

getProjectByID(project_id: string) {
    this.projectService.getProjectById(project_id).subscribe((data: any) => {

        data.project.projectImages.map(image => {
            image.path = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`${this.apiUrl}/${image.path}`);
            return image;
        });
        this.project = data.project;
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

}

check out the docs [here](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Comment: in your component. can you edit and add your component too?

Comment: Its the same class you are using, just one more DI and some modification to projectImage array

Comment: @SachinGupta I added my component, can you please see it?

Comment: Copy the code given by @Obed after you assign to `this.project`.

Comment: I managed to add the DomSanitizer and the request URL is correct, when I copy paste it in the browser the image is displayed but within the <img> tags it says: https://ibb.co/ioBHFT

Comment: @SachinGupta Yes I already did and updated the component, check the picture in the link : https://ibb.co/ioBHFT

Comment: could it be an asynchronous problem?

Comment: the error looks like its from your node server.
input the url directly to check if you can access the image at all

Comment: @Obed Yes I can access the image directly via the browser, I don't know why it the GET request won't go through I've spent more than 5 hours on this images thing

Comment: can you share the url you accessed with?

Comment: yes, `localhost:3000/uploads/152449305965431163305_938377023006717_2908305970268471296_n.png`

Comment: yea, might be more than an image problem.
can you set up a minimal stackblitz?, because this code works at my end with mock data

Comment: The error was that apiUrl: string = "localhost:3000"; should be apiUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173836/discussion-between-obed-and-hadh).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using express in your node app, you need to include a static route to the resources/uploads directory (express static routes) like the following:

app.use(express.static('resources/uploads'))